# Synonymize [azure-sql-database] to [sql-azure]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

While reviewing suggested edits I ran into a tagging suggestion, in which both [sql-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-azure) and [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database) were to be added to the question. As I have no idea about the topic, I looked at the tags:

- [sql-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-azure): 2438 questions
- [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database): 7 questions, oldest dated Oct 9 (2015)
- Identical tag wikis: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-azure/info) vs [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-sql-database/info)

As I don't have any rep in these tags, I can't suggest synonyms for them. And rightly so: I can't be sure that they are actually the same. So I'm bringing this to the attention of those more familiar with the area: are these synonyms? If not, shouldn't at least one of the tag wikis be changed to highlight the differences?

To the layman the fact that the post ratio is 2438:7 would suggest that [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database) is no more than the result of some mistagging, which can be easily reversed in this early stage.

Comment: These two tags are used for the same purpose. According to [the Azure SQL Database product page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) the name of the product is SQL Database. Although the ration of questions asked is 2438 to 7, it would make sense to merge the tag to fit the name of the actual product. This is why I believe azure-sql-database makes more sense to use.

Comment: While this request is over a year old, it should be done. These two tags reference exactly the same thing. The product used to be called "SQL Azure" but Microsoft has since rebranded it as "SQL Database" or "Azure SQL Database" depending on the documentation you refer to.

Comment: @Jaxidian thanks for the feedback! I decided to leave the issue be, on account of lacking domain knowledge and feedback from the community... If you have sufficient tag score, you can submit a synonym suggestion.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't really have any experience with maintaining tags here at SO so I doubt I have sufficient "tag score" (I'm assuming that's a score associated with maintaining tags), but I am very familiar with this domain (my most formal cred is that I have co-authored an MS Press book for Azure cert training). The link that elfisher linked above should also be sufficient proof from Microsoft that the product is in fact called "SQL Database" right now. For the purpose that SO serves, I believe the best tag is [tag:azure-sql-database] and not just "sql-database".

Comment: @Jaxidian "tag score" means your score in the given tag on main:) If you have enough (more than 5, I think), you can suggest a synonym for the tag [on the corresponding page of the tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-sql-database/synonyms). If other users approve of it (2 or 3 needed), the synonym will stick. In case this happens, please leave a message here, or even better: an answer to this question:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks for this info! Quick Q: Does it matter whether I do one or the other? In other words, is there a "main" or "primary" one or something like that? Because technically, "sql-azure" is incorrect whereas "azure-sql-database" is correct.

Comment: @Jaxidian yes, there is a primary one; the synonyms get mapped to that. Looking at something like [ecmascript-6](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-6/synonyms), I would say that you need to suggest the synonym on the page of the correct one. The text on that page seems to suggest the same thing: "*If you know of common, alternate spellings or phrasings for this tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future.*".

Comment: Okay, that's the information I need. Apparently I lack the tag score though. I'll correct that and come back here after I make the suggestions once I have the score. Thanks!

Comment: @Jaxidian good luck with that. Of course it only takes a few retags;)

Comment: I clearly don't know how to work this system as well as you! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Belated update: [sql-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-azure) is now a synonym of [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database). Thanks to everyone involved.